# SQL - use inside 'where' 'over (partition by...)'

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get results from a sql query in which the title runs more than once?  This shows the correct values ​​for 'PPP' but filtering `AND (count(*) over (partition by TITLE)) > 1` does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    AAA,
    BBB,
    CCC,
    count(*) over (partition by TITLE) as PPP
FROM 
    my_tabel
WHERE
    AAA IS NOT NULL
    AND BBB = 'SOMETHING'
    AND (count(*) over (partition by TITLE)) > 1
;
```

**returned error**

```
ERROR: window functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

When i used

```
...
    WHERE
        AAA IS NOT NULL
        AND BBB = 'SOMETHING'
;
```

everything is displayed correctly, but I want a column where PPP > 1

Comment: Try a derived table.

Comment: Try `HAVING PPP > 1` instead.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Please [edit] your post and tell us the exact error message. Also, SQL Window Functions don't work in the `WHERE` part of your query. You can wrap that query in another query though: `select * from (select ..., count(*) over ... as pos, from ...) foo where pos > 1)`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Sorry, unfortunately, window functions don't work in `HAVING` either, at least not for Pg but I doubt that MySQL is better here...

Comment: 'ERROR: column "ppp" does not exist' when i use 'HAVING PPP > 1'

Comment: Yeah.. Now I remember why you always need to wrap your query into a subquery, when you want to filter by a window function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window functions cannot be used in `WHERE` clauses as their result is calculated after the rows, that satisfy the `WHERE` clause were fetched. Wrap another `SELECT` around it and filter in the `WHERE` of this `SELECT`.

```
SELECT aaa,
       bbb,
       ccc,
       ppp
       FROM (SELECT aaa,
                    bbb,
                    ccc,
                    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY title) ppp
                    FROM my_tabel
                    WHERE aaa IS NOT NULL
                          AND bbb = 'SOMETHING') x
       WHERE ppp > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a CTE as follows and use PPP from CTE to add filters:

```
    WITH cte AS(
    SELECT
        AAA,
        BBB,
        CCC,
        count(*) over (partition by TITLE) as PPP
    FROM 
        my_tabel
    WHERE
        AAA IS NOT NULL
        AND BBB = 'SOMETHING'
        )
    Select *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE PPP > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unique identifier for each row -- which you should -- just use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where aaa is not null and bbb = 'something' and
      exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.title = t.title and
                    t2.aaa is not null and t2.bbb = t.bbb and
                    t2.id <> t.id
            );
```

This assumes that you don't actually need the count for other purposes.